# Complex SQL query finding the row before a row containing a specific text

Tags: sql, oracle

Given a table with 2 columns: `table_id` and `marker`.

I want to find the row *before* the row where  `marker`='GeneticMutant'

What kind of query is that, I am new to Oracle SQL Developer. Thanks!

```
-------------------------
`table_id`   |   `marker`
1000         |   ccgcccgccc
2000         |   GeneticMutant
3000         |   bbcbbccgggcddd
4000         |   cccgccgdddcccc
5000         |   GeneticMutant
6000         |   cgcgcbabsshdhd
7000         |   GeneticMutant
8000         |   cgcgcgcgcbbcbcc
9000         |   GeneticMutant
```

**Desired Output**

1000,4000,6000,8000

Comment: Would you mind in explaining a little better? A sample set of rows and what would be the desired result ?

Comment: You probably want the LEAD() function.  But, what do you mean be "before"?  Based on what order?  (There is no intrinsic order in a relational database.)  As Jorge already mentioned, a clearer explanation of what ou are trying to do would be helpful.

Comment: Yes, we need to know how you want to sort this data, since we can't consistently find a row 'before' another row without sorting.

Comment: thanks for the great comments guys, i've given sample data and desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analityc function [LAG](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions070.htm) helps you to read previous rows:

```
with t as (
  select 1 id, 'NoGeneticMutant' marker from dual union all
  select 2, 'HalfGeneticMutant' marker from dual union all
  select 3, 'GeneticMutant' marker from dual union all
  select 4, 'AnotherGeneticMutant' marker from dual union all
  select 5, 'DifferentGeneticMutant' marker from dual union all
  select 6, 'GeneticMutant' marker from dual union all
  select 7, 'AmazingGeneticMutant' marker from dual union all
  select 8, 'UltimateGeneticMutant' marker from dual union all
  select 9, 'GeneticMutant' marker from dual
)
select t.*
  from t
     , (select id
             , marker
             , lag(marker) OVER(order by id) prev_marker 
          from t
       ) t1
 where t.marker = t1.prev_marker
   and t1.marker = 'GeneticMutant'

ID  MARKER
2   HalfGeneticMutant
5   DifferentGeneticMutant
8   UltimateGeneticMutant
```

Get rid of the `WITH` clause and replace `"t"` with your table. Also you have to specify your order, I used `ORDER BY ID` you can have your own order field

Comment: may i know what is t1 in this case?

Comment: t1 is an alias of the subquery

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the `LAG()` function, which provides access to multiple rows. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions070.htm

This is the example from the link above, that shows how to access the previous row. Of course an `ORDER BY` clause is necessary to be able to know what the previous row is.

```
SELECT last_name, hire_date, salary,
   LAG(salary, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY hire_date) AS prev_sal
   FROM employees
   WHERE job_id = 'PU_CLERK';

LAST_NAME                 HIRE_DATE     SALARY   PREV_SAL
------------------------- --------- ---------- ----------
Khoo                      18-MAY-95       3100          0
Tobias                    24-JUL-97       2800       3100
Baida                     24-DEC-97       2900       2800
Himuro                    15-NOV-98       2600       2900
Colmenares                10-AUG-99       2500       2600
```